# How to add editText and buttons dynamically using LayoutInflater and set a unique id for them?

Tags: java, android, dynamically-generated

I am doing adding specifications on the product and I want to that when users click on `add_field_btn` it will show the XML file contains of two editText with a delete button on the side using the LayoutInflater. But I don't know how to implement the adding of a unique id for every editText that are generated.

Below is my code:

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_products);

    backBTN = findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    backBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AddProductsActivity.this, StoreHomeActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("userid", userID);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.mid_to_left, R.anim.right_to_mid);
        }
    });
}

public void onAddField(View v) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_specification_item_layout, null);
    parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount());
}

public void onDelete(View v) {
    parentLinearLayout.removeView((View) v.getParent());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on right way; just check this below function that i modified.

```
int myTagCount=0;

public void onAddField(View v) {

               myTagCount++;

                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_specification_item_layout, null);

                TextView tv_delete = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_delete);
                tv_delete.setText("Delete");

                tv_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                         parentLinearLayout.removeView(view);
                    }
                });

                view.setTag(myTagCount);

                parentLinearLayout.addView(view);

   }
```

I use `inflater` this way. This will also helps you.

For `getting value with Tag`, check this:

```
      for (int i = 0; i < parentLinearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View view = parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
            if (view.getTag().equals(myTagCount)) {
                EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt1);

                String myText = editText.getText().toString();
                break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: How can I input a unique id if I add an editText instead of TextView?

Comment: you can use setTag to view or EditText to identify unique it with id

Comment: Also my delete button id not working. Can you explain to me how to delete a specific inserted view when the delete button corresponding it was clicked?

Comment: Thank you so much! Lastly how can I input a unique tag when every time the users clicked the `add button` ?

Comment: @Mr.Baks I mention that in my updated ans. check it. you need to take count for this.

Comment: I work! but how to get the edittext value using the tag? Sorry I am still new to this,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201185/discussion-between-bhoomika-patel-and-mr-baks).

Comment: I am getting an error in this `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference`

Comment: wich was at the line `if (view.getTag().equals(myTagCount)) {`

Comment: While getting values::   In parentLayout there are 10 child layouts (each child layout contain one edittext and one button) then how to retrieve 10 edit texts data

Comment: @sri, please read answer properly. i mention it there. Check for Loop, where myText  is textsdata.

Comment: @sri  You may use loop inside loop.

Comment: @Mr.Baks Facing same issue , could you please share the solution

Comment: @BhoomikaPatel java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
wich was at the line if (view.getTag().equals(myTagCount))